# PHP Basic email form all messages are from ( Unknown ) despite reply working

Tags: php, html, forms, email

[link to PHP File](http://www.richie.id.au/TAFE/form/php/form1_send.php)
[Link to HTML File](http://www.richie.id.au/TAFE/form/form.html)

Ok so I am doing my first php form and I have tried Googling this and didn't have any luck (if anyone knows any good tutorials on basic php or php forms I have been looking at a lot of them and could use a good one).

Anyway basically I can't figure out why my emails get sent with from ( Unknown ) in Hotmail, even though when I go to reply I get the correct email put in.

Here is the HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My First Basic Form</title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
</style>

<!-- Form Opening Tage -->
<table width="600">
<tr><td>
<form method="post" name="form1" action="http://www.richie.id.au/TAFE/form        /php/form1_send.php"><br /><br />
<table width="600" border="5" bordercolor="#990000">

<!-- Name Field -->
<tr><td>Name:</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="name" size="40" /></td></tr>

<!-- email Field -->
<tr><td>Email:<br /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="email" size="40" /><br /><br /></td></tr>

<!-- Message Field -->
<tr><td>Message: <br /></td></tr>
<tr><td><textarea name="message" width="100%" rows="12" cols="60" style="resize:none;">    </textarea><br /><br /></td></tr>

<!-- Sbumit Button -->
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" /><br /><br /></td></tr>

</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the PHP page

```
<?PHP

// $name variable declared as name that was inputed into text field
$name = $_POST['name'];

// $email variable declared as email that was inputed into text field
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];

// Email to show the message as coming from
$email_from = $_POST["$visitor_email"];

// Message text asigned to variable message
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Email subject
$subject = 'New form submission from richie.id.au';

// Email Body
$email_body = "New message from: $name.\n\n Message:\n\n $message\n";

// Email address to send form submission email to
$to = "richie_hayward_01@hotmail.com";

// headers
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

// Function that actually sends the mail
mail($to,$subject,$email_body,$headers);


?>
```

Comment: I don't know what happened but the emails are taking ages to come through now where as before they where instant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in below line in your php code

```
// Email to show the message as coming from
$email_from = $_POST["$visitor_email"];
```

$email_from is blank and that is the reason for unknown sender.

Comment: I tried removing email_from and just using visitor email and now the form is not even emailing me at all                      http://www.richie.id.au/TAFE/form/form.html

Comment: it's weird, I am not getting any PHP error but my form is not emailing anymore.

Answer (score 2):

`$email_from = $_POST["$visitor_email"];` should be just `$email_from = $visitor_email;` or `$email_from = $_POST['email'];`

Although, why you have two PHP variables for the same thing, I don't know.  You could even do this:

`$email_from = "$name <$visitor_email>";`

Although you may want to sanitise the `$name` and `$visitor_email` variables to make sure they
are valid according to [RFC 5322, section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4).

Comment: Thanks nice response sorry I know it was noob question, this is my first php script.